# php mail form doesn't send mail

Tags: php, html

I seem to have a problem with an email form I am making.
the form worked correctly until I added some extra parts to it. however, even when I comment my changes, it won't work. 
I thought the problem might be due to some syntax error, but It doesn't seem to be so. 
I do not get any error message 
below is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    $num=$_REQUEST['num'];
    $desc=$_REQUEST['desc'];
    $subject="einak";
    $nomr=$_REQUEST['nomr'];
    $sphr=$_REQUEST['sphr'];
    $cylr=$_REQUEST['cylr'];
    $angr=$_REQUEST['angr'];
    $addr=$_REQUEST['addr'];
    $diar=$_REQUEST['diar'];
    $noml=$_REQUEST['noml'];
    $sphl=$_REQUEST['sphl'];
    $cyll=$_REQUEST['cyll'];
    $angl=$_REQUEST['angl'];
    $addl=$_REQUEST['addl'];
    $dial=$_REQUEST['dial'];
    $type=$_REQUEST['type'];
    $matter=$_REQUEST['matter'];
    $color=$_REQUEST['color'];
    $message=$num."<br />".$nomr."<br/>".$sphr."<br/>".$cylr."<br/>".$angr."<br />".$addr."<br />".$diar."<br />"."<br />".$noml."<br/>".$sphl."<br/>".$cyll."<br/>".$angl."<br />".$addl."<br />".$dial."<br />".$desc."<br />".$type."<br />".$matter."<br />".$color."<br />";
    $email='info@toosoptic.ir';
    $headers='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
    mail("mail@example.com",$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "ارسال شما موفقیت آمیز بود";
} else {
    echo "<form method='post'>
                <input name='num' id='num' type='text' /> <br />
                <input type='text' name='nomr' id='nomr' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='sphr' id='sphr'> <br />
                <input type='text' name='cylr' id='cylr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='angr' id='angr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='addr' id='addr'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='diar' id='diar' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='noml' id='noml' > <br />
                <input type='text' name='sphl' id='sphl'> <br />
                <input type='text' name='cyll' id='cyll'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='angl' id='angl'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='addl' id='addl'  > <br />
                <input type='text' name='dial' id='dial' > <br /> 
                <textarea id='desc' name='desc'> </textarea>          
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='bifocal' id='type1' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='progres' id='type2' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='single' id='type3' />
                <input name='type' type='radio' value='decen' id='type4' />
                <input name='matter' type='radio' value='glass' id='mat1' />
                <input name='matter' type='radio' value='plastic' id='mat2' />
                <input name='color' type='radio' value='single' id='col1' />
                <input name='color' type='radio' value='decen' id='col2' /> 
                <input type='submit' id='sb' value='ارسال اطلاعات' />
                <input type='text' name='name' id='name'  > <br />
                <input type='add' name='address' id='address'  > <br /> 
            </form >
            <p id='confirmation'></p>
            <input  type='submit'  id='vis' onClick='vis(); return false;'  value='تایید اطلاعات'/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: which error message you getting when try to send mail  if you are using secure server then you need to pass valid mail in from option also

Comment: i think you doesn't select any one of your radio buttons

Comment: problem is, I don't get any error message

Comment: Are you running this from localhost?

Comment: @SatishSharma I do not think so, I only have three sets of radio boxes

Comment: @BeatAlex nope, from my website

Comment: Broken heart has figured this out.

Comment: @soheils: Are you trying to post the form using Ajax ???

Comment: I think `<input type='submit' id='vis' onClick='vis();`: `return false;` might be creating the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have not define the name in the submit button here:

```
 <input type='submit' id='sb' value='ارسال اطلاعات' />
```

Replace above code with the below code:

```
 <input type='submit' id='sb' name='email' value='ارسال اطلاعات' />
```

You are checking the code `if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))` and there is no email field the form as I see.

Basically this check is used for verifying that form have submitted or not(as generally other do). So you need to add the `name='email'` in the submit button attribute to execute the if condition code..

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a mime header but you're not setting any mime encoding, that might be one issue ;-)
Try using a dedicated package such as [PEAR/Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/mail/) (and [PEAR/Mail/Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)) or [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).